# In Mechanize what is the cookiejar and how does it differ from cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

How does Mechanize::CookieJar differ from the Mechanize::Cookies array? There must be some difference but after poking around for a little bit I can't seem to find a good explanation?

Answer (score 3):

It seems from the [official documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) that the CookieJar and cookies are very similar indeed:

```
# File lib/mechanize.rb, line 208
def cookies
  @cookie_jar.to_a
end
```

Usually, a Cookie Jar has also the interesting ability to be saved on disk and reloaded later on (see the `save_as` and `load` method on the Cookie Jar).